# In data.table, what is the difference between taking dot(.) and 'c' in j while using .SD? How does it work?

Tags: r, data.table

Take DT as mtcars data table.

```
DT <- as.data.table(mtcars)
```

While taking multiple arguments in 'j' with .SD, if we use dot(.) before j like below code

```
DT[ , .(lapply(.SD, sum), .N), by = (cyl) ]
```

the result comes in vertical order with without the column names.

*O/P:*

> cyl     V1      N
>
> 1:   6     138.2    7
>
> 2:   6    1283.2    7
>
> 3:   6      856     7
>
> 4:   6      25.1    7
>
> 5:   6      21.82   7
>
> 6:   6     125.84   7
>
> 7:   6      4       7
>
> 8:   6      3       7

But when I replace that with the dot(.) in 'j' with 'c' like below,

```
DT[ , c(lapply(.SD, sum), .N), by = (cyl) ]
```

the result comes in horizontal order.

*O/P:*

> cyl   mpg   disp   hp  drat     wt   qsec vs am gear carb   N
>
> 6 138.2 1283.2  856 25.10 21.820 125.84  4  3   27   24  7
>
> 4 293.3 1156.5  909 44.78 25.143 210.51 10  8   45   17 11
>
> 8 211.4 4943.4 2929 45.21 55.989 234.81  0  2   46   49 14

In another case, without lapply, exactly the opposite happens.

```
DT[ , c(sum(mpg), .N), by = (cyl) ]
```

gives the output vertically

*O/P:*

> cyl    V1
>
> 1:   6 138.2
>
> 2:   6   7.0
>
> 3:   4 293.3
>
> 4:   4  11.0
>
> 5:   8 211.4
>
> 6:   8  14.0

whereas a dot(.) in 'j' gives the output horizonatlly.

```
DT[ , .(sum(mpg), .N), by = (cyl) ]
```

*O/P:*

> cyl    V1  N
>
> 1:   6 138.2  7
>
> 2:   4 293.3 11
>
> 3:   8 211.4 14

Why does this happen? Why the result is ordered in such way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
DT[,    .(sum(mpg), .N), by = (cyl) ] # equal, creates a list with 2 elements (2 columns)
DT[, list(sum(mpg), .N), by = (cyl) ] # equal, to above

DT[,    c(sum(mpg), .N), by = (cyl) ] # creates a vector of length 2 (equal to 2 rows)
```

---

another simplified example.

```
DT[ ,    .(col1 = 1, col2 = 2), by = (cyl) ]
DT[ , list(col1 = 1, col2 = 2), by = (cyl) ]

DT[ , c(element1 = 1, element2 = 2), by = (cyl) ]
```

---

To address your last point,

```
DT[ , c(element1 = 1, element2 = 2, element3 = list(3)), by = (cyl) ]
DT[ , c(element1 = 1, element2 = 2, element3 = 3      ), by = (cyl) ]
```

You need to learn more about the `c` function.

So as `lapply` (listapply) returns a list the `c` will add the `.N` as new LIST ELEMENT in `c(lapply(.SD, sum), .N)`.

So you end up with n list elements and therefore n columns.

---

Just for fun:

```
DT[ , c(lapply(.SD, sum), .N), by = (cyl) ]
DT[ , c(sapply(.SD, sum), .N), by = (cyl) ] # sapply will simplify the result into a vector, therefore c() will combine into a vector and you end up with many rows.
```

Comment: @Deb see if this is enough explanation.

Comment: Thank you so much! This explains a lot. But, I still have one doubt.  `DT[ , (lapply(.SD, sum)), by = cyl ]` returns a list with all columns as I understand but why does`'DT[ , .(lapply(.SD, sum)), by = cyl ]` returns the result in many rows when lapply should also return a list? What is the dot changing here?